# Symbol not found libboost_regex-mt.dylib

Tags: macos, command-line, macos-catalina

Every time I run the file on the command line it says:

> dyld: Symbol not found:  __ZN5boost11basic_regexIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE9do_assignEPKcS7_j
>
> Referenced from: /Users/username/Desktop/NervaWallet/nerva-wallet-cli
> Expected in: /usr/local/opt/boost/lib/libboost_regex-mt.dylib  in
> /Users/username/Desktop/NervaWallet/nerva-wallet-cli
>
> Abort trap: 6

Can anyone of you help me fix this problem

Thanks